# How to apply required field validator on date using javascript in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<script>
    $(".js-flatpickr").flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "m/d/Y",
    });
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="content" id="app">
        @include('pages.partials.application-steps')
        @include('partials.error')
        <form class="js-validation-material" action="{{ route('personal.post') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf        
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block-header block-header-default">
                    <h3 class="block-title" style="text-align: center;">Personal Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center py-20">
                        <div class="col-xl-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-material">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{{ $employee->first_name }}" required>
                                        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-material">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="{{ $employee->last_name }}" required>
                                        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-material">
                                        <input type="text" required class="js-flatpickr js-flatpickr-enabled form-control{{ $errors->has('date_of_birth"') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Click here to choose date" value="{{ $employee->date_of_birth}}">
                                        <label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth *</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('date_of_birth'))
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('date_of_birth') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-material">
                                        <select class="form-control{{ $errors->has('marital_status') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="marital_status" name="marital_status" value="{{ old('marital_status') }}" required>
                                            <option value="">...</option>
                                            <option value="Married" @if ($employee->marital_status == "Married") selected @endif>Married</option>
                                            <option value="Unmarried" @if ($employee->marital_status == "Unmarried") selected @endif>Unmarried</option>
                                            <option value="Other" @if ($employee->marital_status == "Other") selected @endif>Other</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label for="marital_status">Marital Status *</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('marital_status'))
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('marital_status') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-12">Are you legally eligible to work in Canada? *</label>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mb-5">
                                        <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="eligible" id="yes-eligible" value="Yes" {{ ($employee->eligible=="Yes")? "checked" : "" }} required>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="yes-eligible">Yes</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mb-5">
                                        <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="eligible" id="no-eligible" value="No" {{ ($employee->eligible=="No")? "checked" : "" }}>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="no-eligible">No</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
          </div>

            <nav class="clearfix push">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary min-width-100 float-right" id="save">Save & Continue</button>
            </nav>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
            data: {
                form: {
                    commute: '',
                    status: ''
                }
            },
            methods: {
                refresh_flatpickr: function() {
                    console.log('asa');
                    $(".js-flatpickr-status").flatpickr({
                        dateFormat: "m/d/Y",
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // SIN Number Add Dashes
            $('#sin').keyup(function() {
                var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
                if (foo.length > 0) {
                    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
                }
                $(this).val(foo);
            });
            $("#save").click(function(){
                var eligible = $("input[name='eligible']:checked").val();
                if(eligible == 'No'){
                    alert("You need to be eliable to work in Canada to get this job.");
                    return false;
                }
                ***var date_of_birth = $("input[name='date_of_birth']").val();
                if(date_of_birth != ' '){
                    alert("Choose date of birth");
                    return false;
                }***
            }); 
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

This highlighted part is not working in script on click of save button ..

Please help !! i want to make my date as required field using javascript so how can i apply required field validator on it? For eligible, same coding is working !!

In my controller, already date is having required validator like below -

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'first_name' => 'required',
         'last_name' => 'required',
         'date_of_birth' => 'required',
         'marital_status' => 'required',
         'preferred_language' => 'required',
         'eligible' => 'required',
        ]);

       if ($validator->fails()) {
           return redirect()
               ->back()
               ->withErrors($validator)
               ->withInput();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var date_of_birth = $("input[name='date_of_birth']").val();

if (date_of_birth != undefined && date_of_birth.length == 0) {
     alert("Choose date of birth");
     return false;
}
```